# How can I use Enzyme React Test .find method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to learn Enzyme + Jest testings in React components and I'm having an error in using `.find` method in Enzyme.

**Error**

```
Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

      19 |         onAddNew={onAddNew} />);
      20 |
    > 21 |      component.find('button.btn-primary').simulate('click');
         |                                           ^
      22 |      expect(onAddNew).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

I checked the rendered html and I can see the button and class name exactly as I wrote in the find method.

[image]

According to this [link](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html), I can write the Enzyme selector as `div.className`.  I thought we can write Enzyme selectors as JQuery selectors.  So, I used `button.btn-primary` or `button.btn btn-primary`, but it doesn't work.

However, if I used `.find('Button')` it can find it.  It shows an error that, it found 2 nodes because I have 2 Buttons in the component.  Does it mean that `.find` method performs the search on React Components rather than rendered DOM document?  If yes, how can I write the selector to find the Primary button?  Is there a way to find it without using first() or (0)?

Please see the following codes as detail:

**workoutAdd.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import WorkoutAdd from '../workoutAdd';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
    const 
        onChange = jest.fn(),
        onChangeDate = jest.fn(),
        onAddNew = jest.fn(),
        toggle = jest.fn(),
        item = {};

    const component = shallow(<WorkoutAdd
        toggle={toggle}
        modal={true}
        item={item}
        onChange={onChange}
        onChangeDate={onChangeDate}
        onAddNew={onAddNew} />);

     component.find('button.btn-primary').simulate('click');
     expect(onAddNew).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

**Component - workoutAdd.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Modal, ModalBody, ModalHeader, ModalFooter, Button
    , Form, FormGroup, Label, Input
} from 'reactstrap';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

export default class WorkoutAdd extends Component {

    render() {
        const {
            modal,
            toggle,
            item,
            onChange,
            onChangeDate,
            onAddNew } = this.props;
        return (
            <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle} centered>
                <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>Add New Workout</ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                    <Form>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label for="Date">Date</Label><br />                            
                            <DatePicker
                                name="date"
                                id="Date"
                                className="form-control"
                                selected={item.date}
                                onChange={onChangeDate}
                                dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                maxDate={new Date()}
                            />                            
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label for="WorkoutType">Type</Label>
                            <Input
                                type="select"
                                name="workoutType"
                                onChange={onChange}
                                value={item.workoutType}
                                id="WorkoutType">
                                <option>Running</option>
                                <option>Cycling</option>
                            </Input>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label for="Calories">Calories</Label>
                            <Input
                                type="number"
                                name="calories"
                                id="Calories"
                                value={item.calories}
                                onChange={onChange}
                                placeholder="Calories burnt"
                            />
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Form>
                </ModalBody>
                <ModalFooter>
                    <Button color="primary" onClick={onAddNew}>Save</Button>{' '}
                    <Button color="secondary" onClick={toggle}>Cancel</Button>
                </ModalFooter>
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}
```

**UPDATED Answers**

The code I used in the question (`button.btn-primary`) doesn't work because I'm using Bootstrap component to render Button.  If you are using traditional button html to render your button, it will work.

There are many ways to achieve this requirement.
*Method 1*

`console.log(component.debug());` is the key utility to analyze how Enzyme renders and sees the component.

`component.find("Button").at(0).simulate('click')` as mentioned by Matt.
However, you cannot move the position of the buttons / add new buttons and the test will fail.

*Method 2*

```
component.find('Button[color="primary"]').simulate('click');
```

or

```
component.find('Button').find({ color: 'primary' }).simulate('click');
```

You can use the above codes to find the right button with any attribute/prop.  By using these, your test codes do not couple to the implementation of the component.  You do not need to worry about the position of the button anymore.  Having said that, if you have 2 buttons with 'primary', you will need to find out another way to identify the button uniquely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're only `shallow` mounting, it would be `Button.btn-primary` or `Button.btn.btn-primary`. You can confirm this by writing `console.log(component.debug());` inside of your `it` test, and it'll print out the `DOM` structure as `enzyme` sees it.

If you want, you can also generalize your `.find()` to `component.find("Button").at(0).simulate('click')` or in layman's terms "find a Button component at position 0 and simulate a click". Or simply `component.find(".btn-primary").simulate('click')`. You have many options to find a DOM element and it becomes a personal preference (although, I'd much prefer a more specific selector, especially if you ever `mount` a component).

As a side note, be care about generalized imports:
`import WorkoutAdd from '../workoutAdd';` can resolve to `workAdd.test.js` instead of `workoutAdd.js` if they're within the same folder. So if you ever run into issues where jest states `expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)`, then you'll know why.

Comment: Thanks very much for -> console.log(component.debug());   Because of that, I can see what Enzyme sees now.

Comment: After searching so much, console.log(component.debug()); solved my issue, thanks